# Label stretches with text Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

Im trying to get the text I insert to go to another line if it doesn't fit in my xcode 7. Whenever I type more text than what would usually fit in one line instead of going on line 2 or 3 like I specified it just stretches itself inside the label. Is there something I am missing?

**[image: ViewController:]**

[image: XCode]

I am doing this in a collection view hence the cell. The following bit of code is how I get my my text into my viewcontroller at runtime:

```
let appleProducts = ["IPADIPADIPADIPADIPADIPADIPADIPADIPADIPAD", "HIIII", "Custom"]

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.appleProducts.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.titleLabel?.text = self.appleProducts[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For multiline `UILabel` you should use:

```
label.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
label.numberOfLines = 0
```

Or set `UILabel` `Line  Breaks` and `Lines` parameters in Storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a UITextView instead of a UILabel. UITextViews are built to allow for multiple lines off the bat.

Comment: did not work, it just doesn't have '...' but doesn't show the whole thing on a different line

Comment: Wait the UITextView shows a ... Instead of being the text to the next line? Have you tried revising the font size or size of the textview?

Comment: sure, adjusting it to smaller to fill one line is a reasonable strategy, but that wasn't what I was looking for because now you can barely read the text.

Comment: Makes sense, reasonable problem. I am surprised it isn't working on its own, though. If anything will allow for multiline functionality, it should be UITextView. It's hard for me to know what you should do without having a visual of the result you get using it

Comment: I do have a screenshot above, maybe im misinterpreting your statement about visual. However, this is what it is, when I am working with the UItextview, there is no ... after if the text exceeds the text box's width. However the leftover text is still not visible whatsoever. With the label, it just states '...'.

Comment: Can't you scroll down inside the UITextView to see the rest of the text? It shouldn't be moving out of the boundary. Also, I meant a visual when you use UITextView, not a label.

Comment: Nope just a single line no scroll

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90748/discussion-between-choward-and-newbeginnings).